# What's a simple pattern to chunk parse data for writing csv?

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, export-to-csv, libreoffice-calc

I have several years worth of data in a single large XML file (~700k lines), which I've parsed with Beautiful Soup, and then wrote to CSV with `csv.writer()`. Only, now I'm having problems previewing the long text values in my spreadsheet app (LibreOffice).

*Goal.* Chunk the texts and pair each with it's related date.

*Input:* **'date'** and **'text'** **elements** from the XML tree. Date text is self-explanatory, text element values are approximately **5-10k words**.

*Output*. **List of tuples**. The text element is chunked by a static *word count*. **Each chunk** is paired with it's original date value effectively creating multiple records for each date in the final CSV. For example:

```
[(date1, "text1...."),(date1, "text2...."),(date1,"text3...."), ... (daten,"text1..."),(daten,"text2...")]
```

(*Multiple records for each date is OK, because the analysis is at the word/token level, and not sentence/paragraph level--order doesn't matter*)

Experimenting with the value of `n`, I can better control the line lengths across the various applications I use on the data. Whatever the solution, clearly it would happen at or after BeautifulSoup's `findAll()` output for 'text' and before `csv.writer()`--naturally.

Currently it's simple enough to make a list of dates and a list of texts and `zip()` them together, because they're both lists of the same size. This design creates two lists of different sizes, so I need to insert `date` in the chunking step.

What's a simple *and elegant* pattern to chunk parse data for writing csv and maintaining the date-text relations?

//I've rewritten the question to more explicitly name the input & output.

Comment: Could you just have more columns? I.E. text1, text2, text3 etc.

Comment: I'm going to perform more analysis on the CSV file after the Python parsing using someone else's Java applet. The input space for the this analysis is just two variables. In other words, I can have three rows with the same date, but not one date with three different texts. All the sorting has to happen in Python to CSV step.

Comment: After my edits, @SpencerRathbun 's comment might be unclear. I believe his suggestion is to write the tuple as `[(date1, text1, text2, text3),(date2, text1...),...(daten, text1,text2)]`--which is different from the example.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [python's generators](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/). This allows you to create a "pipeline" of operations that can be chained together. Each step can do one thing, and you can add additional steps as needed.

For instance (Psuedocode):

```
def getTags():
tags = Beautifulsoup.find_all()
for tag in tags:
    yeild (date, tag)

def splitText(input):
    for (date, text) in input:
        for t in text.split("."):
            yield (date, t)

def writeLines(input):
    for line in input:
        csv.write(line)

tags = getTags()
lines = getLines(tags)
writeLines(lines)
```

I like this layout personally.

Comment: Frankly, I don't know Python so well that your pseudo code without a comment will communicate what the pattern is you're showing me... (>_<) I get the tags are elements, but I'm not seeing the extraction and since there are different dates and texts _all in the same file_, I would have to add another generator for the text...and then join them?

Comment: @xtian I assumed you knew how to take apart the tags from soup already. I was just demonstrating the generator format to stream each segment of work along to the next function. Unless you gave me more details about your inputs and your outputs (Scoped your question better), I'm not going to be able to do more than give you a general pattern to follow.

Comment: This answer provoked me to look for more info.  The best explanation I found was at http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html.